# OpenCV Error: Bad argument in ERClassifierNM1

Tags: python, c++, opencv, detection

I run opencv 3.2.0, ubuntu 14.04, and latest opencv_contrib.

I run examine: 
https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/samples/textdetection.py

But it have show err:

```
$ python textdetection.py scenetext_word01.jpg 

textdetection.py
   A demo script of the Extremal Region Filter algorithm described in:
   Neumann L., Matas J.: Real-Time Scene Text Localization and Recognition, CVPR 2012
Extracting Class Specific Extremal Regions from 9 channels ...
(...) this may take a while (...)
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Default classifier file not found!) in ERClassifierNM1, file /home/vietnam/opencv_and_contri/opencv_contrib/modules/text/src/erfilter.cpp, line 1022
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "textdetection.py", line 38, in <module>
    erc1 = cv2.text.loadClassifierNM1(pathname+'/trained_classifierNM1.xml')
cv2.error: /home/vietnam/opencv_and_contri/opencv_contrib/modules/text/src/erfilter.cpp:1022: error: (-5) Default classifier file not found! in function ERClassifierNM1
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using relative paths in the parameters for cv2.text.loadClassifierNM1() and cv2.text.loadClassifierNM2() 
So now that part of the code looks like this:

```
erc1 = cv2.text.loadClassifierNM1('./trained_classifierNM1.xml')
er1 = cv2.text.createERFilterNM1(erc1,16,0.00015,0.13,0.2,True,0.1)

erc2 = cv2.text.loadClassifierNM2('./trained_classifierNM2.xml')
er2 = cv2.text.createERFilterNM2(erc2,0.5)
```

I'm not sure why this works (it did for me), but I tried this after looking at a solution posted for a similar problem in VS2015 here: https://github.com/cesardelgadof/OpenCVBinaries/issues/1

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Trying with absolute path e.g. **"/usr/lib/opencv-3.2.0/opencv_contrib-3.2.0/modules/text/samples/trained_classifierNM1.xml"** worked in my case for Ubuntu 16.04, C++

Comment: What version of tesseract and leptonica did you install?

Comment: @SarahM tesseract 3.05.00
 leptonica-1.74
  libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.4.2) : libpng 1.2.54 : libtiff 4.0.6 : zlib 1.2.8

Comment: Thank you. Does the project work in Debug mode or Release? because I installed them and tested the project on release (it worked) but don't know how to move to debug mode, especially does it require to build them again with cmake.

Comment: @SarahM yes it's working both in debug and run. I had no problem. But I'm not using python, I use C++ version.

Comment: Can you tell me how to run it in debug? I'm using C++ too.

Comment: @SarahM I basically use Eclipse CDT Debug mode, nothing special.